# How to load associated objects when fetching all instances of a JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Given the following code:

> **User** entity

```
@Entity
class User {
  ...
  @OneToMany (mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Immovables> immovables;
  ...
}
```

> **Immovables** entity

```
@Entity
class Immovables {
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name = "user_id")
  private User owner;
  ...
}
```

> Data access code

```
public List<User> selectAll() {
    return (List<User>) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT user FROM User user").getResultList();
}
```

When I call the `selectAll` method as shown above, I would like to have the `User` objects in the returned `List` to also have all the associated `Immovables` objects. However, I find that the `List` of `Immovables` inside each `User` is empty.

I am using JPA 2.1, Spring 4, Hibernate and Postgres.

Comment: SO many problems here, not least of which is the use of raw types. My overall advice: Use Spring Data JPA and let it build the query for you. If you're asking about something else, please *format your code* and explain the question in more detail.

Comment: in USER  : @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Immovables> immovables; in Immovable   : @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User owner;    my method return user!and list Of Immovables!but Immovables list a EMpty!!! why?   thank for tenderness

Comment: Since you are using FetchType eager and @OneToMany/@ManyToOne annotations, the child fields should be there. Your code looks ok and the problem has to be in other place. Be sure that actually there are rows associated with that User in the DB or the tables are correctly associated with its respective FK...

Comment: thanks to community!!!

Comment: @Jalex problem solved?